# submit app to the app store without create new version

Tags: ios, app-store

please i have an question about update the app in app store  and i need help from you , 
it's possible to submit update app to the app store without creating new version ?

for example sometimes i need to update the some links for some site it's not good every week i send the update to the user and every week the version is increasing ,it's good to create the new version if i make some changes on my app .
but if i need to change some links it's good to update the app to the app store without creating new version , is any way can i do this?

thanks advance

Comment: What links are you talking about? Something in the app's description shown in the App Store, or some link shown in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why you almost always see 3-part version numbers, such as 2.4.32

MajorVersionChange **.** MinorVersionChange **.** Update

So, no, you cannot submit an update without a version change, but you can just change that last piece.

As a side note, for what you're describing, it's common to build in "on-the-fly" data updating... For example, each time the user starts your app, have your app check a remote server for "new links." When there *are* new links, save them to local storage and use them until there are newer ones on the remote server.

Comment: thank you for answer friend but if i change the last piece the user must buy my app again or  can get the app again?

Comment: No... the user will *never* have to buy your app again if you are updating the version. They only have to buy it again if you submit it as a new, different app.